# remove or hide JSF message

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

When I added message, I am unable to remove it.

```
< h:message id="myError" />

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myError", new FacesMessage("Fatal error!"));

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages();
```

After that `.getMessages()` returns empty list.

How could I remove or hide posted message?

Comment: have you try this FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myError", null); or
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myError", new FacesMessage(""));

Comment: Could you please give us more informations?